# How to remove unwanted URL from google cache

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console, googlebot, google-crawlers

We bought a new domain from HugeDomains.com before a month and made it live last week.

Before we move live, the advertisement published by HugeDomains.com got cached in search engines.

Now we need to **remove that cached URL from all search engines**.

Following is the **Pattern of URL** got cached, it's just a **query string** getting passed

http://www.example.com/?fp=ah1QKL6n%2FlECnlCZX2M7prGsvtbv8ddXendjKdEvTBtzHaEkYE%2BEk37MD1iDIPnimmKBVn7jZKj%2BPGqRUxNQzA%3D%3D&prvtof=ytNnOdijWVo6UL0CLJYkUNs043cNT%2BNtJQ5d5VD69Ac%3D&poru=RLg1S8TlJRc59ObVEdjqkbBOZjhk%2FIf%2BH8W1DtjVOk5VRbieT62uHl%2FGfuWk4d%2FnOfDQwYDvqLza3nG76SMxZA%3D%3D&

I have used Disallow in **Robots.txt** to remove that but its not working, following will be the code

> Disallow: /*?fp=
>
> Disallow:
>   /?fp=ah1QKL6n%2FlECnlCZX2M7prGsvtbv8ddXendjKdEvTBtzHaEkYE%2BEk37MD1iDIPnimmKBVn7jZKj%2BPGqRUxNQzA%3D%3D&prvtof=ytNnOdijWVo6UL0CLJYkUNs043cNT%2BNtJQ5d5VD69Ac%3D&poru=RLg1S8TlJRc59ObVEdjqkbBOZjhk%2FIf%2BH8W1DtjVOk5VRbieT62uHl%2FGfuWk4d%2FnOfDQwYDvqLza3nG76SMxZA%3D%3D&

I even enabled a 302 Redirect for this query string **fp=** to my **home page**

Please let me know a way to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Robots.txt disallow should do it, but another good way is to return a `410 Gone` result, then google will stop indexing it since it'll see this page has disappeared.

**Edit**

Looks like I was wrong about Robots.txt, but right about `410 Gone` response: 
[Reference](http://www.seoblog.com/2014/06/google-indexing-deleted-pages/)

Comment: Thanks Joanvo, Will look into this and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this with robots.txt.

Just wait. I think the most search engines will recognize that your website is new so they will crawl it again in near future.

Otherwise you can create a google-webmaster account and send your url to google to crawl it again.

EDIT: You're also able to disallow [url-parameter in webmaster tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en).

Comment: Hi @almost we already have a google-webmaster account and we have submitted all the pages for crawling and we even updated out sitemap too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a 301 permanent redirect for Google to drop old indexed page. If you do 302, Google will try to crawl that url once in a while as it is temporary. Ignoring query parameters does not help in clearing the cache, it just sends signal saying the url with query param is same as the one without it. I guess that is not what you want. My suggestion would be to do a 301 permanent redirect if you encounter query param fb.

Right now i doubt google handles 404 and 410 lot differently. So you can do a 410 as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Google webmaster** can help you in removing outdated/ cache content from Google search results

1. Copy your domain Cached URL
2. Browse to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals
3. Follow **Request** instructions.

The cache can be removed in a few numbers of hours. Google search engine crawls to new/current URL contents.

[image: Source: Google webmaster]